# I am unable to run HIVE functions in my DBeaver tool

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql, teiid

I am trying to run some hive functinos in Dbeaver tool but it always giving the below error

What I am trying to run is for example :

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('17-Sep-21', 'dd-MMM-yy'),'dd-MMM-yy');
```

error I am getting :

> SQL Error [30328] [50000]: TEIID30328 Remote
> org.teiid.api.exception.query.ExpressionEvaluationException
>
> TEIID30328 Unable to evaluate timestampadd(SQL_TSI_SECOND,
> unix_timestamp('17-Sep-21', 'dd-MMM-yy'), {ts'1969-12-31 19:00:00.0'})
>
> TEIID30341 Function impala.unix_timestamp is marked in the function
> metadata as a function that must be evaluated at the source.

Comment: its working for me in hue. see if DBeaver uses some auo data conversion before issuing the sql to impala

Answer (score 0):

The full stack trace should contain more information as to why it can't evaluate.  Most of the later versions of Teiid even for pushdown functions will pre-evaluate them if the surrounding expression cannot be pushed.